# Virtualbox command line

Tags: bash, virtualbox

How do I start Virtualbox from the command line and
start a Ruby script on the guest and after the script is done close the guest?
What could be easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the VM with VBoxManage:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm <NameOfVMHere>
```

After the VM has booted you can run a program if you have guest editions installed:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" guestcontrol exec --image <path to program> --username <name>  [--password <password>]  [--wait-exit] [--wait-stdout] [--wait-stderr]
```

Finally, when the program has finished executing you can close the VM with the command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" controlvm <vm> savestate
```

Alternatively, you can shutdown the machine with a [command at the end of the Ruby Script](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.ca/2008/04/shutting-down-windows-from-ruby-code.html)

Comment: But how to start ruby script you say: --image path to program, but I want to start ruby.rb like I do in command line ruby ruby.rb

Comment: I mean as guest to start in the guest ruby or php

Comment: Make a script with the command you normally run and then call the script.

Comment: It gives an error that 'ruby' is not recognized as an internal or external function, even though the ruby executable is in path.